# GraphQL начинающему React - overkill?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

Я даже не устроился еще на работу но почему то в голову запал этот GraphQL. Стоит ли тратить столько сил на него или его используют только нишевые компании и я просто трачу время когда должен вызубрить mern стак?